# Bootstrap 3 panel and floating image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I can't build a responsive design with Bootstrap 3 panel when I have floating image next to it. The text can be short or long. I want the panel to fit in the free space left from the image and not to go behind it.

How can I do that?

Here is the example:

```
<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 padding-top-40">
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/34299/herbs-flavoring-seasoning-cooking.jpg" class="float-img">
      <p>
         Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source.
      </p>
      <h2>Don't leave me hanging</h2>
      <p>
        There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable.
      </p>
      <div class="panel panel-danger">
        <div class="panel-body">
          It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.
          <br>
          Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer">
          <a class="btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block" href="#">
            <i class="fas fa-user-circle"></i> Register
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

```
<style>
body {
  width: 1100px;
}
.float-img {
  float: right;
  width: 500px;
}
</style>
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/Stefan-Pavlov/pen/WNLrBqR)

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Responsive Design Example</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <style>
    body {
      width: 1100px;
    }
    .content-container {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      align-items: flex-start;
    }
    .float-img {
      width: 500px;
      margin-right: 20px;
    }
    .panel-container {
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="content-container">
          <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/34299/herbs-flavoring-seasoning-cooking.jpg" class="float-img">
          <div class="text-content">
            <p>
              <!-- Your first paragraph here -->
            </p>
            <h2>Don't leave me hanging</h2>
            <p>
              <!-- Your second paragraph here -->
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="panel-container">
          <div class="panel panel-danger">
            <div class="panel-body">
              <!-- Your panel content here -->
            </div>
            <div class="panel-footer">
              <!-- Your panel footer content here -->
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This approach gives you more control over the layout and allows the text to surround the image while keeping the panel separate. You might need to adjust the styles further based on your specific design needs.

Comment: I want the text to surround the image, because it can be very long and will have 1 very long column and one with image and many free space.

Comment: refer the recently edited approach which gives you more control over the layout and allows the text to surround the image while keeping the panel separate. You might need to adjust the styles further based on your specific design needs.

Comment: The effect is the same as if I put the panel in a separate row below without any CSS. It seems that panel can't surround the image as normal text do, so maybe I will do it in a new row. Thanks anyway.